# Migrate struts to spring tags in jsp

Tags: python, spring-boot, jsp, abstract-syntax-tree, struts-1

I have used the Abstract Syntax Tree parsing from python using the **ast** module example - https://www.javatpoint.com/python-ast-module

Now I got the use case to replace few tags in the JSP file.
**Example** :

```
<logic:equals property=“fieldname” value=“somevalue”> 
 </logic:equals>
```

To be replaced with

```
<c:if test=“fieldname.somevalue”> 
</c:if>
```

But I am not able to find any library which loads the jsp file as AST for parsing.
I need to migrate the struts based jsp tags to spring based jsp , I have the list of tags to be migrated but not sure how to load the JSP as AST.

So that I can automate the struts based jsp tags to spring based jsp tags as shown in the example code above (logic:equals to c:if)

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: You're asking for a JSP parser that allows access to the AST in the AST format you want?

Comment: @DaveNewton yes so that I can replace the tags